# How much CPU + Memory I need in android(2.3 OR ABOVE) phone for develop native application

Tags: android, smartphone

I am web developer that going to develop on android native application.

For that purpose i need to buy smartphone - i will not use use it for private needs.

My Question:
How much CPU + Memory I need in android(2.3 OR ABOVE) phone for develop native application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try buying smallest one. In the end it should work for worst case.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Another question how much smallest - CPU+MEMORY?

Comment: It does not matter. You probably want that your application will run on all phones. You need phone just for debugging and debug code does not consume that much cpu and memory no matter what you are doing. In any case you can still run much of your code on in emulator and use phone just for final testing if needed. There is no IDE to install on phone for this purpose.